# Run shell script as sudo user along with its internal content on unix rhel

Tags: shell, unix, rhel7

I have below script named as sample.sh
        #!/bin/bash
        echo "inside script file"
        echo `whoami`
        echo `cftping -v`
        echo "Ping completed"
I am running it as other user with the help of below command.
       sudo -H -u xfbcft bash -c 'bash /data/_temp/sample.sh'

I am getting below output:
*xfbcft

/data/_temp/sample.sh: line 4: cftping: command not found

Ping completed*

When I sudo to xfbcft directly then I can run 'cftping -v' command but not via above shell script. Could anyone guide me here?

Comment: Typically this is differences in the profile of the two users, is the cftping on the path of the shell script environment ?

Comment: Not sure as what is meant by on path but it's working when I go and do sudo to xfbcft user and then run that cftping. Is there any way to give standard path for that xfbcft user for this command?

Comment: The path is an environment variable that is set in your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc file.  It can be different for each user. If you compare the results of  "sudo echo $PATH" and then  "echo $PATH" after you receive the error and check that the path to cftping is present in the environment path for the bash script.

Comment: thanks, I found way to directly run command using sudo.   sudo -u xfbcft -i bash -c 'cftping -v `